# Does MQTT Support User to User Messages

Tags: mqtt

I know that using MQTT topics devices can subscribe to them. But is there any way that a IoT device can send some message to a target IoT device (by device id or something) without using a topic or is there any standard topic for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to communicate without a topic, but you can create a topic for any purpose.  So typically if you wanted to send a message to another client, you would publish it somewhere in the hierarchy of topics to which that client is subscribed.

That could be as simple as something like `device/12345/inbound` or whatever you prefer.  And because topics can have hierarchy, in addition to whatever detail you put in the body, you can also encode categorization of your message into the topic, much as RESTful APIs often do in a URL.

A good reason for using target-specific (or owner-account-specific) topics is that the most easy solutions for MQTT security compartmentalization are topic-scope.